# Angular debugger won't continue

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This has been going on for some months but we are really getting anoyed by it.

So in the summer of 2020, we upgraded our packages in our angular project and all of the sudden our debugger stopped working. Let me illustrate it with a .GIF.

[image]

Our breakpoints do get hit, but clicking on continue, step over, ... simply does not do anything. We created a new angular project to test if that would debug and yes it does. We then copied all of our configuration to that project and the new project still debugs. The only difference now between our old and our new project as far as we know is some packages.

Is there anybody else that has got this problem before and knows how to fix it? We can only assume it has to do with an upgrade in either angular or node or npm.

We do not have the deprecated extensions debugger for chrome btw. But installing this did not make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the ["[Deprecated] Debugger for Chrome" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) and setting the `type` in your `launch.json` to `legacy-chrome`:

```
{
  "type": "legacy-chrome",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach to Chrome",
  "port": 9222,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_javascript-debugging for more information.